# Is there a way to escape non-alphanumeric characters in Nokogiri css?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I have an anchor tag:

```
file.html#stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1
```

Trying to pull the referenced content in Nokogiri:

```
documentFragment.at_css('#stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1')
```

fails with the error:

```
unexpected '.1' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS:
:Node:0x007fd1a7df9b40 @type=:CONDITIONAL_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fd1a7df9b90 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["*"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fd1a7df9cd0 @
type=:ID, @value=["#unixnut4-CHP-1-SECT-2"
]>]>]' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

Just trying talk through this - I think Nokogiri is complaining about the `.1` in the selectorId, because `.` is not valid in an html id.

I don't own the content, so I really don't want to go through and fix all the bad IDs if it is avoidable.  Is there a way to escape non-alphanumeric selectors in a nokogiri `.css()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1'>foo</div>
```

The string in question, `stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1`, *is* a [valid HTML ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), but it *isn’t* a [valid CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors) — the `.` character isn’t valid there.

You should be able to escape the `.` with a slash character, i.e. this is a valid CSS selector:

```css
#stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2\.1
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t seem to work in Nokogiri, there may be a bug in the CSS to XPath translation that it does. (It does work in the browser).

You can get around this by just checking the `id` attribute directly:

```ruby
documentFragment.at_css('*[id="stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1"]')
```

Even if slash escaping worked, you would probably have to check the `id` attribute like this if it value started with a digit, which is valid in HTML but cannot be (as far as I can tell) expressed as a CSS selector, even with escaping.

You could also use XPath, which has an [`id` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) that you can use here:

```ruby
documentFragment.xpath("id('stuff-morestuff-CHP-1-SECT-2.1')")
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  I didn't realize that there were different rules on ids and selectors.